# Create a view in which i take a table in sql and inner join with itself

Tags: sql

So i have been given a task in which i have to create a view of a table and that table will have to inner join with itself, where parent_id = id. I did this part of the task which was fairly easy.
This is the solution to the first problem :

```sql
create view v_res_business_sector as
select rb1.id, rb1.create_uid, rb1.write_uid, rb1.create_date, rb1.write_date, rb1.name , rb1.active, rb1.parent_id, rb1.Code
 from res_business_sector as rb1
INNER JOIN res_business_sector as rb2
ON rb1.parent_id = rb2.id
```

But now i have to alter the view. I have to add a column named is_subsector which is bit, where
is_subsector = 1 if parent_id is not null.

My first solution was as below, which was not approved cause it wasn't in the correct way:

```
alter view v_res_business_sector as
select *,
CASE WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS is_subsector
from v_res_business_sector
```

Comment: *" which was not approved cause it wasn't in the correct way"* What do you mean "wasn't in the correct way"? Also please don't tag conflicting products; MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products.

Comment: A view is like a macro in some other languages - the definition of the view is "expanded out" into the query which it's used in. As such, you can't define a view based on itself.

Comment: @Larnu sorry for the tags, they said that it wasnt the correct answer given to the task, i need to change my alter view, or do it in a completely different way which i am not much familiar

Comment: ALWAYS include the complete, exact error message when you encounter one. Don't hide the error behind a meaningless phrase like "wasn't in the correct way". And notice that your original view used an INNER JOIN which means it ignores all the "top level" parent rows (that have no parent).

Comment: Well you retag the RDBMS you actually using, @xristosratsas . As for the problem, you `VIEW` is trying to call itself; that won't work. Have a look at the definition of the `VIEW` at the beginning of your question, that shows you what a `VIEW`'s definition should actually look like.